# Function as a denominator in python graph label (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm currently trying to make a graph in python. I want my x axis label to be 1/(x^2 + a^2)^3/2, but expressed properly as a fraction with superscripts etc. However I'm having real trouble doing that.

I got to:
    plt.xlabel(r'$\frac{1}{$($x^2$+$a^2$)^{3/2}}$')

but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you've got way more `$`s than you need. try `r'$\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}}$'`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much, you're a lifesaver :)